# Exception: Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.BlobStore Exception

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, rbs

In SharePoint 2010 I get this error from RBS. This error is shown in event viewer. I could not find any questions around about this error. This error is shown very ofthen. Too often I would say.

```
Message ID:24, Level:ERR , Process:7484, Thread:27
Blob store <FilestreamProvider_1> threw this exception:
Operation: Unknown
BlobStoreId: 1
Log Time: 6/2/2016 10:12:29 PM
Exception: Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.BlobStoreException: There was a generic database error. For more information, see the included exception. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean& marsCapable)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.Data.BlobStores.FilestreamBlobStore.SyncTransaction.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Data.BlobStores.FilestreamBlobStore.LazyInitOnlyOnce`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Data.BlobStores.FilestreamBlobStore.SyncTransaction.SyncOpenSqlFileStream(String filestreamPath, Boolean asyncReadDisabled)
   at Microsoft.Data.BlobStores.FilestreamBlobStore.FilestreamReaderStream..ctor(String filestreamPathName, SyncTransaction syncTransaction, Boolean asyncReadDisabled)
   at Microsoft.Data.BlobStores.FilestreamBlobStore.FilestreamStoreLibraryBase.ReadBlob(Byte[] storePoolId, Byte[] storeBlobId)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.BlobStores.FilestreamBlobStore.FilestreamStoreLibraryBase.ReadBlob(Byte[] storePoolId, Byte[] storeBlobId)
   at Microsoft.Data.BlobStores.BlobStore.ReadBlobInternal(Request request)
BlobStoreException Code: OperationFailedAuthoritative
From my personal observations, this also makes some problems for the custom applications.
```

It is possible that this error comes because of several different errors:

Cannot connect to SQL Server. 'server - name' not found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

These errors are given in SQL server:

`SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c, state 14 while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The Windows error code indicates the cause of failure.`

```
SQLVDI: Loc=SignalAbort. Desc=Client initiates abort. ErrorCode=(0). Process=5648. Thread=14776. Client. Instance=. VD=Global\Data Protector_(DEFAULT)_WSS_Content_090036205_0_SQLVDIMemoryName_0.

BackupVirtualDeviceFile::RequestDurableMedia: Flush failure on backup device 'Data Protector_(DEFAULT)_WSS_Content_090036205_0'. Operating system error 995(The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.).
```

Any ideas why this happens?

P.S. I know it is very long, I will be happy if anyone helps to redact it.